# How can I hook structure members in frida

Tags: c++, ghidra, frida

I have a code like this:

```
class CURLNetRequest : public CNetRequestBase
{
    DEFINE_LOGCLASS;
    
    struct ProxySettings
    {
        void initFromConfig();
        
        String  host;
        int     port;
        String  username;
        String  password;
    };

    struct AuthSettings
    {
        AuthSettings( AuthMethod m, const String& u, const String& p )
        : method(m)
        , user(u)
        , password(p)
        {}

        const AuthMethod method;
        const String user;
        const String password;
    };
...
```

I want to hook the `structure` members i.e. `user` and `password` using `frida`. so far I did like below:

```
const some_func_pointer = Module.getExportByName('librhodes.so', '_ZN3rho3net14CURLNetRequest10CURLHolder11set_optionsEPKcRKNSt6__ndk
112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEESD_PNS0_11IRhoSessionEPNS_9HashtableISB_SB_EERKNS1_13ProxySettingsERKNS1_12AuthSettingsE');
const some_func = new NativeFunction(some_func_pointer, "void", ["int", "pointer"]);
Interceptor.replace(some_func_pointer, new NativeCallback(function (size, data) {
  console.log(size)
  console.log(data.readUtf8String())
  some_func(size, data);
}, "void", ["int", "pointer"]));
```

and I can only get the `AuthMethod m` which could either be `POST` or `GET` in this case. How can I hook others like `username` and `password`.

FYI, this is [rhomobile](https://github.com/rhomobile/) built app, and the above snippet taken from the [open source code](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/0296271a56699e15fef45209473fb9bcd20a5639/platform/shared/net/CURLNetRequest.h), so apparently decompiling `librhodes.so`  produces some stripped functions, etc.

please help me with this.

Comment: Based on your question which had been [posted on SO some days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099271) you have made no progress at all. At least you should mention what you have tried so far even if it didn't work.

Comment: still no progress, may be if you know a way to debug `lib.so` on `apks` you could help me with this. any resource any link?

Comment: Search Stackoverflow-com and reversengineering.stackexchange.com for the [frida] tag, the number of posts is not very high. In the end you can hook the method using name or address - just what matches your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332781/frida-hook-native-non-exported-functions/68335254#68335254 I already gave you a lot of hints on stackoverflow, as I don't know what type is used in your case you have to investigate it yourself, look at the dumped memory and check out how to read it.

Comment: @Robert, I have decompiled [librhodes.so](https://file.io/gb5tHwBN8wdP) on `ghidra` and then tried to find the address of the function wanted to hook and then wrote this `frida script`: ```//Hook function setAuthUser @ 0x8e427c
Interceptor.attach(Module.findBaseAddress('librhodes13.5.1.so').add(ptr(0x7e427c)), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("=> setAuthUser(" + args[0] + ")");
    },
    onLeave: function(result) {
       console.log("setAuthUser() => " + result);
    }
});```

Comment: @Robert but still no output I got don't know what wrong

Comment: I mean now I am trying to hook the function `setAuthUser` and unable reach any result I have [shared](https://file.io/gb5tHwBN8wdP) with you the lib [here](https://file.io/gb5tHwBN8wdP). please could you check that if it is right way to construct the script above. thanks

Comment: Sorry but Stackexchange is a Q&A site, not a "I post work and others to the job site". I gave my best to help you finding the correct approach, but in your case it seems that you have not tried anything of what I suggested, at least it is not visible in your next question that you have tested anything.

Comment: Tried all your suggestions here and SO but things not connected up.

Comment: @Robert, I have posted [Question ](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30729/how-can-i-enumerate-and-hook-all-non-exported-functions-in-lib-so-using-frida)  just to make it clear all what I tried.